# awk extract multiple groups from each line

Tags: regex, awk, grouping

How do I perform action on all matching groups when the pattern matches multiple times in a line?

To illustrate, I want to search for `/Hello! (\d+)/` and use the numbers, for example, print them out or sum them, so for input

```
abcHello! 200 300 Hello! Hello! 400z3
ads
Hello! 0
```

If I decided to print them out, I'd expect the output of

```
200
400
0
```

Comment: For Googlers: note that with `gawk`, aka. "GNU awk", you can actually do what the title says (not the question) in one line (e.g. via. piping): `| gawk -v RS='' '{ print gensub(/()()/, "\\1\\2", "g"); }'` :D This supports multi-line (due to the `-v RS=''`) and matching sub-groups (due to using gawk's `gensub`)!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a simple syntax, and every awk (nawk, mawk, gawk, etc) can use this.

```
{
    while (match($0, /Hello! [0-9]+/)) {
        pattern = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH);
        sub(/Hello! /, "", pattern);
        print pattern;
        $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is `gawk` syntax. It also works for patterns when there's no fixed text that can work as a record separator and doesn't match over linefeeds:

```
 {
     pattern = "([a-g]+|[h-z]+)"
     while (match($0, pattern, arr))
     {
         val = arr[1]
         print val
         sub(pattern, "")
     }
 }
```

Comment: That `sub` at the end makes a huge difference! Sadly it took me some time to try it out... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="Hello! ";}
{
    gsub(/[^0-9].*/,"",$1)
    if ($1 != ""){ 
        print $1 
    }
}' file
```

Comment: Nice, but won't work for more complex patterns like /([a-g]+|[h-z]+)/ and will match over a linefeed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no gawk function to match the same pattern multiple times in a line. Unless you know exactly how many times the pattern repeats.

Having this, you have to iterate "manually" on all matches in the same line. For your example input, it would be:

```
{
  from = 0
  pos = match( $0, /Hello! ([0-9]+)/, val )
  while( 0 < pos )
  {
    print val[1]
    from += pos + val[0, "length"]
    pos = match( substr( $0, from ), /Hello! ([0-9]+)/, val )
  }
}
```

If the pattern shall match over a linefeed, you have to modify the input record separator - RS