# how to get sub-expression value of regExp in awk?

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I was analyzing logs contains information like the following:

```
y1e","email":"","money":"100","coi
```

I want to fetch the value of money, i used 'awk' like :

```
grep pay action.log | awk '/"money":"([0-9]+)"/' ,
```

then how can i get the sub-expression value in ([0-9]+) ?

Comment: To clarify, you want the numeric value after the `:`?

Comment: A sed version would be: `sed -r 's|^.*money":"([0-9]*)".*|\1|'` or if you don't want to print lines that do not contain `money`: `sed -n -r 's|^.*money":"([0-9]*)".*$|\1|p'`

Comment: @Op De Cirkel Thank you! Seems 'sed' is more powerful! Why 'awk' has no such design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have GNU AWK (`gawk`):

```
awk '/pay/ {match($0, /"money":"([0-9]+)"/, a); print substr($0, a[1, "start"], a[1, "length"])}' action.log
```

If not:

```
awk '/pay/ {match($0, /"money":"([0-9]+)"/); split(substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH), a, /[":]/); print a[5]}' action.log
```

The result of either is `100`. And there's no need for `grep`.

Comment: Thanks. Pretty near to what i expected, but is there a more clever way?

Comment: @RoyHu: The 1 in the array index refers to the capture group. I don't know of any other way to do that in awk or gawk. Gawk has a function `gensub()` that can be used for *replacing* the contents of a capture group. You could use it, but the expressions would be more complex for the use in your question.

Comment: Thanks. And i got one using gensub :  grep pay action.log | awk -F "\n" 'm=gensub(/.*money":"([0-9]+)".*/, "\\1", "g", $1) {print m}'

Comment: If you have `gawk` installed, in the first example, the print clause can be simplified to `print a[1];`

Answer (score 2):

Offered as an alternative, assuming the data format stays the same once the lines are grep'ed, this will extract the money field, not using a regular expression:

```
awk -v FS=\" '{print $9}' data.txt
```

assuming data.txt contains

```
y1e","email":"","money":"100","coin.log
```

yielding:

```
100
```

I.e., your field separator is set to `"` and you print out field 9

Comment: Thanks. but the field where contains "money" info may not be fixed!

Comment: I think of one more way:                                              grep pay action.log | awk -F "\n" 'm=gensub(/.*money":"([0-9]+)".*/, "\\1", "g", $1) {print m}'

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference group 1 of the regex

I'm not fluent in awk but here are some other relevant questions

[awk extract multiple groups from each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116193/awk-extract-multiple-groups-from-each-line)

[GNU awk: accessing captured groups in replacement text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555173/gnu-awk-accessing-captured-groups-in-replacement-text)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks you ! inspired by 'gensub' i got                           grep pay user_action.log | awk -F "\n" 'm=gensub(/.*money":"([0-9]+)".*/, "\\1", "g", $1) {print m}'

Answer (score 0):

If you have `money` coming in at different places then may be it would not be a good idea to hard code the positional parameter.

You can try something like this -

```
$ awk -v FS=[,:\"] '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/money/) print $(i+3)}' inputfile
```

Comment: Thanks that works.but i want to know how awk fetch the group 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep pay action.log | awk -F "\n" 'm=gensub(/.*money":"([0-9]+)".*/, "\\1", "g", $1) {print m}'
```

Comment: You should refactor out the `grep`. Remember that `grep 'foo' file | awk '{ bar }'` is basically always better written as `awk '/foo/ { bar }' file`.