# Extract multiple independent regex matches per line

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

For the file below, I want to extract the two strings following "XC:Z:" and "XM:Z:". For example:

- 1st line output should be this: "TGGTCGGCGCGT,  GAGTCCGT"
- 2nd line output should be this: "GAAGCCGCTTCC, ACCGACGG"

The original version of the file has a few more columns and millions of rows than the following example, but it should give you the idea:

```
    MOUSE_10        XC:Z:TGGTCGGCGCGT       RG:Z:A  XM:Z:GAGTCCGT   ZP:i:33
    MOUSE_10        XC:Z:GAAGCCGCTTCC       NM:i:0  XM:Z:ACCGACGG   AS:i:16
    MOUSE_10        ZP:i:36 XC:Z:TCCCCGGGTACA       NM:i:0  XM:Z:GGGACGGG   ZP:i:28
    MOUSE_10        XC:Z:CAAATTTGGAAA       RG:Z:A  NM:i:1  XM:Z:GCAGATAG
```

In addition, each of following criteria would be a bonus but is not mandatory if you can get it to work:

- use standard bash tools: awk, sed, grep, etc. (no GAWK, csvtools,...)
- assume we don't know the order in which XC and XM appear (although I'm fairly certain XC is almost first, but I am unsure how to check). In the output, however, the XC-string should always be before the XM-string, if at all possible.

The answers from here [awk extract multiple groups from each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116193/awk-extract-multiple-groups-from-each-line?newreg=5a10d566023a4261b4503b16a9ca8743) come awfully close to it, but whenever I try using match(...) I get a "syntax error near unexpected token" message.

Looking forward to your solutions!

Thanks,

Felix

Comment: easy with `GAWK`

Comment: You should show your code that comes up with the error — we can probably fix that easily.

Comment: Would you ever get 3 lots of `XC:Z:` and 2 lots of `XM:Z:` on a single line?  Can you have one pattern without the other?  What exactly is the required output — should the prefix be preserved?  Are you wanting one line per pattern in the output, even if there are 2 or more matches in a single input line, so the total number of lines in the output could be greater than the number of lines in the input.  It isn't hard to do; it is just a question of working out exactly what you want done.  Producing an MCVE ([MCVE]) with sample output data too (the input shown is good) helps.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I expect exactly one occurence of each string (XC:Z: and XM:Z:) per line, thanks for the clarifying question. I agree the complete output on top of the two supplied examples would get closer to a real MCVE, sorry for not having added it!

Comment: Why not add it now? wrt your syntax error - either you're running old, broken awk or you're calling awk from the command line and bash is interpreting the `!`. Without knowing more about your environment and what you're executing and your expected output, etc. we can't help you much.

Answer (score 1):

With sed you can capture non-space characters after `XC:Z:` and `XM:Z`:

```
sed -n 's/.*XC:Z:\([^[:blank:]]*\).*XM:Z:\([^[:blank:]]*\).*/\1, \2/p;' file
```

You can add a second `s` command for reversed values:

```
sed -n 's/.*XC:Z:\([^[:blank:]]*\).*XM:Z:\([^[:blank:]]*\).*/\1, \2/;s/.*XM:Z:\([^[:blank:]]*\).*XC:Z:\([^[:blank:]]*\).*/\1, \2/;p;' file
```

Comment: Thanks @SLePort, this does for me what it should. I understand this assumes XC:Z: is always before 'XM:Z:', is that correct?

Comment: I edited to cover the case where `XM:Z` is before `XC:Z`.

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` solution may help you in same.

```
awk '
/XC:Z:/{
  match($0,/XC:[^ ]*/);
  num=split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),a,":");
  match($0,/XM:[^ ]*/);
  num1=split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),b,":");
  print a[num],b[num1]
}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
TGGTCGGCGCGT GAGTCCGT
GAAGCCGCTTCC ACCGACGG
TCCCCGGGTACA GGGACGGG
CAAATTTGGAAA GCAGATAG
```

Comment: Thanks RavinderSingh13, I like your answer and would like to understand it a little better. Can you explain which values a,b and num,num1 are taking? I assume a and b are arrays that are being created inside the split command, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '{c=p="";                               # need to reset c and p before each line
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                    # for all fields in the line
          if($i~/^XC:Z:/) c=substr($i,6)      # check pattern from the start of field
          else if($i~/^XM:Z:/) p=substr($i,6) # if didn't match check other other pattern 
        if(c && p) print c,p}' file           # if both matched print

TGGTCGGCGCGT GAGTCCGT
GAAGCCGCTTCC ACCGACGG
TCCCCGGGTACA GGGACGGG
CAAATTTGGAAA GCAGATAG
```

this will print the last matches if there are multiple instances on the same line.  Here is another one with slightly different characteristic.

```
$ awk 'function s(x) {return ($i~x)?substr($i,6):""}
      {c=p="";
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
         c=c?c:s("^XC:Z:"); p=p?p:s("^XM:Z:");
         if(c && p) 
           {print c,p; next}}}' file

TGGTCGGCGCGT GAGTCCGT
GAAGCCGCTTCC ACCGACGG
TCCCCGGGTACA GGGACGGG
CAAATTTGGAAA GCAGATAG
```

this will print the last of the repeated match before the first match of the other.  It they appear in pairs, will print the first pair.

Comment: Hi @karakfa, really like your solution1, seems to work well on my file, thanks. Three things are unclear to me. First, shouldn't we reset c and p (c=p="") inside the for-loop rather than before it? Second, why do you use 'else if' instead of 'if'? The third point is: does the '^'-sign not usually stand for the start-of-line, if so how does it work here although there's always at least one column ("Mouse_10") before it? (#3 is me being too lazy to google, feel free to ignore if you're unmotivated to explain regex to me - but #1 and #2 would be good to resolve!)

Comment: added explanation.  `if else` is better since it can only match one pattern at a time, if it matched the previous pattern, there is no need to check the other one.  If this solution solved your question, you'll need the up vote and/or select as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we don't know the order in which XC and XM appear
You can try this sed

```
sed -E 'h;s/(XC:Z:.*XM:Z:)//;tA;x;s/(.*XM:Z:)([^[:blank:]]*)(.*XC:Z:)([^[:blank:]]*)(.*)/\4,\2/;b;:A;x;s/(.*XC:Z:)([^[:blank:]]*)(.*XM:Z:)([^[:blank:]]*)(.*)/\2,\4/' infile
```

explanation :

```
sed -E '
h
# keep the line in the hold space
s/(XC:Z:.*XM:Z:)//;x;tA
# if XCZ come before XMZ, go to A but before everything restore the pattern space with x
s/(.*XM:Z:)([^[:blank:]]*)(.*XC:Z:)([^[:blank:]]*)(.*)/\4,\2/
# XMZ come before XCZ, get the interresting parts and reorder it
b
# It is all for this line
:A
s/(.*XC:Z:)([^[:blank:]]*)(.*XM:Z:)([^[:blank:]]*)(.*)/\2,\4/
# XCZ come before XMZ, get the interresting parts
' infile
```

Comment: This code does what is should, and the explanations are very useful, thanks! And I'm in awe in face of your incredibly sed-skills, very powerful!

Answer (score 0):

Using POSIX `awk`, you can only use the string-function `match(s,ere)` as defined by [IEEE Std 1003.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) :

> `match(s, ere)`
>
> Return the position, in characters, numbering from 1, in
>   string s where the extended regular expression ere occurs, or zero if
>   it does not occur at all. RSTART shall be set to the starting position
>   (which is the same as the returned value), zero if no match is found;
>   RLENGTH shall be set to the length of the matched string, -1 if no
>   match is found.

The patterns you want to match are `XM:Z:[^[:blank:]]*` and `XC:Z:[^[:blank:]]*`. This however assumes you do not have any string which contains something like `PXM:Z:` (i.e. an extra non-blank character advancing the searched string). When the pattern is found in the line `$0`, then you only need to extract the important parts, which start 5 characters later.

The following code does the above:

```
   awk '{match($0,/XM:Z:[^[:blank:]]*/);xm=substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)}
        {match($0,/XC:Z:[^[:blank:]]*/);xc=substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)}
        {print xc","xm}' <file>
```

As you can see, the first line extracts `XM`, the second `XC` and the third prints the outcome with comma-separator `","`.

Remark - The following assumptions are made here :

- each line contains both an `xm` and `xc` string
- no strings of the type `[^[:blank:]]X[CM]:Z:[^[:blank:]]*` exist

If you are willing to use `gawk`, then you could use the `patsplit` function for string operations (Ref. [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-patsplit_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029)). You can do this with a single regex `/X[CM]:Z:[^[:blank:]]*/`. This gives you directly the requested strings in a single call which include the `XM:Z:` or `XM:C:` part. Afterwards you can easily sort them and extract the last parts.

The following lines do exactly the same in `gawk`

```
   gawk '{patsplit($0,a,/X[MC]:Z:[^[:blank:]]*/) }
         {xc=(a[1]~/^XC/)?a[1]:a[2]; xm=(a[1]~/^XC/)?a[2]:a[1]}
         {print substr(xc,5)","substr(xm,5)' <file>
```

Nonetheless, I believe the `awk` solution is cleaner from a symmetric point of view.